# Why is there a data race in this Go program?

Tags: go, race-condition

I'm trying to store log messages in a buffer to access them only when I get an error. A bit like in [Smarter log handling, the case for opportunistic logging](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/attack-of-the-logs-consider-building-a-smarter-log-handler/). In this example I fetch the logs from the buffer each 5 seconds but I get a data race when I run it with `go run -race code.go`.

I'm using channels to communicate but I'm doing something wrong, obviously.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type LogRequest struct {
    Buffer chan []byte
}

type LogBuffer struct {
    LogInputChan chan []byte
    LogRequests  chan LogRequest
}

func (f LogBuffer) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    f.LogInputChan <- b
    return len(b), nil
}

func main() {
    var logBuffer LogBuffer
    logBuffer.LogInputChan = make(chan []byte, 100)
    logBuffer.LogRequests = make(chan LogRequest, 100)

    log.SetOutput(logBuffer)

    // store the log messages in a buffer until we ask for it
    go func() {
        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

        for {
            select {
            // receive log messages
            case logMessage := <-logBuffer.LogInputChan:
                buf.Write(logMessage) // <- data race
            case logRequest := <-logBuffer.LogRequests:
                c, errReadAll := ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
                if errReadAll != nil {
                    panic(errReadAll)
                }
                logRequest.Buffer <- c
            }
        }
    }()

    // log a test message every 1 second
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
            log.Printf("test: %d", i) // <- data race
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    // print the log every 5 seconds
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

            var logRequest LogRequest
            logRequest.Buffer = make(chan []byte, 1)
            logBuffer.LogRequests <- logRequest

            buffer := <-logRequest.Buffer

            fmt.Printf("**** LOG *****\n%s**** END *****\n\n", buffer)
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(45 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: if your remove log.SetOutput(logBuffer) the race warning goes away. That line sets logBuffer as a global variable which is being used by a go routine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `log` package uses an internal buffer to build-up log messages for output (the `buf` field in [log/Logger](http://golang.org/src/pkg/log/log.go?s=1890:2182#L32)).  It composes the header, appends the data provided by the caller, then passes this buffer to your  `Write` method for output.

In order to reduce allocations, the `log` package recycles this buffer for each log message.  It's not stated in the documentation, but the implicit assumption is that your `Write` method only uses the provided `[]byte` data for the duration of the `Write` call.  This assumption is OK for most outputs, e.g. a file or STDOUT.

To avoid a data race, you need to make an explicit copy of the incoming data before returning from the `Write` function:

```
func (f LogBuffer) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    z := make([]byte, len(b))
    copy(z, b)
    f.LogInputChan <- z
    return len(b), nil
}
```

Comment: FYI, I have done a similar buffered logger that used a `sync.Mutex`-protected `ring.Ring` (circular buffer) of strings.

Comment: What is the advantages of using a `sync.Mutex`-protected `ring.Ring` over this method? Do you have a link?

Comment: Using a `ring.Ring` for storage means that "reading" the log buffer does not clear it, i.e. multiple readers can fetch the last `n` messages.  That was useful for my application.

Comment: FYI: This answer also applies to `fmt.Fprintf`. I had a similar construct as OP where a custom type was implementing the `Writer` interface and in my `Write(...)` method I sent the input `[]byte` to a channel. This worked absolutely fine and led to no races when using the `.Write()` directly, but led to a cryptic data race when using `fmt.Fprintf(w, ...)`. From looking at the source `fmt.Fprintf` does some similar internal buffer reuse as the log package. After creating an explicit copy of the byte slice the race is gone and the behavior is as expected now. Thanks!